# Common Lisp: Beginner's trouble with funcall

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to pass a function as an argument and call that function within another function.

A piece of my code looks like this:

```
(defun getmove(strategy player board printflag)
(setq move (funcall strategy player board))
(if printflag
    (printboard board))
```

strategy is passed as a symbol represented in a two dimensional list as something such as 'randomstrategy

I keep getting the error:
"FUNCALL: 'RANDOMSTRATEGY is not a function name; try using a symbol instead...

When I replace strategy with 'randomstrategy it works fine.
I can also call randomstrategy independently.
What is the problem?

Comment: additionally move is not a defined variable

'randomstrategy is a list: (quote randomstrategy), you cannot funcall that list.

Comment: Your indentation is misleading, and your parentheses are rather obviously not balanced.  I suspect that the use of SETQ is a code smell here.  You should also show how you intend to call this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `strategy` a variable with a functional value? If not, then use the `#'` syntax macro before it, i.e. `#'strategy`, or just (if the function is global) `'strategy`.

WHY? Because arguments of a `funcall` call are evaluated. And your `strategy` symbol is just a variable name in this case. Variable this value `'RANDOMSTRATEGY`. But you should give to `funcall` a function. How to access function if we have a symbol?

Three cases:

1. Symbol may denote a variable with functional value.
2. Symbol may denote a global function (`symbol-function` is the accessor in this case.
3. Symbol may denote a local function (flet, labels and so on).

It looks like you forgot to define `RANDOMSTRATEGY` function.

`(defun RANDOMSTRATEGY …)`

Hmm

```
FUNCALL: 'RANDOMSTRATEGY
```

Maybe you have `(setq strategy ''RANDOMSTRATEGY)`?

Then `strategy` will evaluate to `'RANDOMSTRATEGY`.
Did you notice `'` before the symbol name? `'RANDOMSTRATEGY` <=> `(quote RANDOMSTRATEGY)`; it is not a proper function name.

Comment: What do you mean?
I said I could call it and 'randomstrategy worked fine.
Here is the randomstrategy function:

(defun randomstrategy(player board)
(let*((moves (legalmoves player board)) (r (nth (+ 1(random  (- (nth 0 moves) 1))) moves)))
 r))

Comment: maybe you wrote (setq strategy ''RANDOMSTRATEGY) ?

Comment: There is no setq for strategy. It is only a function parameter. This isn't a problem isn't it?

Comment: How would I go about stripping that quote(?

Comment: How 'RANDOMSTRATEGY  became the value of strategy?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the variable `strategy` does not contain the symbol `randomstrategy` but rather the *list* (!) `'randomstrategy` (which is a shorthand notation for `(quote randomstrategy)`).

Now, you *could*, of course, extract the symbol from the list by way of the function `second`, but that would only cover the real problem up, which is probably somewhere up the call chain.  Try to determine why the argument that is passed to function `getmove` is `'randomstrategy`, not `randomstrategy` as it should be.  (Maybe you erroneously used a quote inside of a quoted list?)

Oh, and don't let yourself be confused by the fact that `(funcall 'randomstrategy ...)` works: the expression `'randomstrategy` does not, after all, evaluate to itself, but to the symbol `randomstrategy`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set strategy anywhere?  It looks like a scoping issue.

Try this

```
(setq strategy 'randomstrategy)
(setq move (funcall strategy player board))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing the code, I'm imagining you're doing something like this:

(defun randomstrategy (a b c) ...)

and then doing this:

(getmove 'randomstrategy x y z)

What you want to do is pass the function "randomstrategy" to getmove using #':

(getmove #'randomstrategy x y z)

In CommonLisp, #' yields the function bound to the symbol, which is
what you want to pass to getmove.

Comment: In Common Lisp, it is perfectly valid to funcall symbols naming global functions.